# ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation not working in kotlin with multiple views

Tags: android, animation, view, kotlin, transition

This is my Kotlin code for activity transition animation

```
    val p1 = Pair.create(imageViewhospitals, "hospitals")
    val p2 = Pair.create(textViewhospitals, "title")

    val options = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                        ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this, p1, p2)
                    } else {
                        TODO("VERSION.SDK_INT < LOLLIPOP")
                    }
startActivity(Intent(this,SplashActivity::class.java),options.toBundle())
```

I am getting an error/warning like

> none of the following function can be called with the arguments
>   supplied

on `ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Finally I have solved this problem by changing from

```
val p1 = Pair.create(imageViewhospitals, "hospitals")
val p2 = Pair.create(textViewhospitals, "title")
```

to

```
val p1 = Pair.create<View, String>(imageViewhospitals, "hospitals")
val p2 = Pair.create<View, String>(textViewhospitals, "title")
```

Comment: what import did you use?

Comment: @seekingStillness androidx.core.util.Pair.create

Answer (score 4):

Import this:

```
import android.util.Pair as UtilPair
```

and then do

```
val pair1 = UtilPair.create<View,String>(yourView,"myTransition")
val pair2 = UtilPair.create<View,String>(view.package_name,"actNameTransition")
val options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this,
                pair1,
                pair2)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
val imgAnim = Pair.create<View?, String?>(galleryImg, "targetImage")
val textAnim = Pair.create<View?, String?>(textTitle, "targettext")
val options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation( activity, imgAnim, textAnim)
```

This works for me using ActivityOptionsCompat instead of using ActivityOptions

Answer (score 3):

Import this

```
import androidx.core.util.Pair
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though I'm using Kotlin, I had to specify the redundant Pair type for the code to run! so just add these:
`<View, String>`

final:

```
    val options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this,
        Pair.create<View, String>(viewHolder.imageView, getString(R.string.shared_animation_imageview)),
        Pair.create<View, String>(viewHolder.tvTitle, getString(R.string.shared_animation_title)))

    startActivity(intent, options.toBundle())
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and in my case i needed to get the imports corrected.  Here's the code that worked for me in addition to the imports.

```
import androidx.core.util.Pair
import androidx.core.app.ActivityOptionsCompat
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat


val intent = Intent(activity, SecondActivity::class.java)
val pair1 = Pair.create<View, String>(view1, "string1")
val pair2 = Pair.create<View, String>(view2, "string2")
val options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(activity, pair1, pair2)
ActivityCompat.startActivity(activity, intent, options.toBundle())
```